# Not a GROUP BY expression (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to aggregate my query by a certain field but I keep getting the error message as stated in the title.

My code is:

```
select cluid, step, count(*) as CNT--, json_value(e.event_payload, '$.type') as type
from VDS_OWNER.PROTO_BEAN_COUNTER_EVENTS_BASE2 e
where json_value(e.event_payload, '$.type') = 'page'
    and e.STEP <> 'overview'
    and ROWNUM <= 10000
group by e.CLUID
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* unaggregated columns in the `select` should be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select cluid, step, count(*) as CNT--, json_value(e.event_payload, '$.type') as type
from VDS_OWNER.PROTO_BEAN_COUNTER_EVENTS_BASE2 e
where json_value(e.event_payload, '$.type') = 'page' and
      e.STEP <> 'overview' and
      ROWNUM <= 10000
group by e.CLUID, e.step;
```

If you only want one row per `CLUID`, then remove `step` from the `select`:

```
select cluid, count(*) as CNT--, json_value(e.event_payload, '$.type') as type
from VDS_OWNER.PROTO_BEAN_COUNTER_EVENTS_BASE2 e
where json_value(e.event_payload, '$.type') = 'page' and
      e.STEP <> 'overview' and
      ROWNUM <= 10000
group by e.CLUID;
```

Or use `listagg()` or some other appropriate aggregation function if you want information about steps but only one row per `CLUID`.